# How yahoo fetches the facebook friends of logged in user who are also shared/read article with/on yahoo?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, yahoo

I wanted to know how yahoo fetches list of logged (facebook) in users only those friends who also has read article on yahoo in order by recency...

link for referance: http://in.news.yahoo.com/ (you must log in with fb and then you will see your friends list in header if any  one of your friends has already sign in on yahoo and read any article)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Once you are logging in yahoo with facebook, yahoo stores your userid and also stores all of your friends' userids.

When your friend 'X' read an article, its sets a flag that 'X' has read it.

Now, when you login, it checks in database and fetches a list of your friends userid's and then checks if anyone of them has read that article too.

If yes, it shows them next to you.